# Global variable changed when reading other value from html

Tags: go, go-fiber

I have defined global variable of `universitySelected` and `domain` at the top of my code, however, the `universitySelected` value was overwritten after `email := c.FormValue("email")`.

For example, the `universitySelected` was "Harvard University" but after `email := c.FormValue("email")`, the `universitySelected` became "ex@harvard.edusity"

Here is how I defined my global variable and where it get overwritten

```
var universitySelected string
var domain string


func HandleRegistration(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    // Get the form values
    email := c.FormValue("email")
    password := c.FormValue("password")
    

    if !strings.Contains(email, ".edu") {

        return c.Render("signup", fiber.Map{
            "UniversityName": universitySelected
            "UniversityDomain": domain,
            "ErrorMessage":     "Email Domain Not Supported",
        })
    }
.
.
.
```

Here is how I get `universitySelected` value

```
func HandleUniversitySelection(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    universitySelected = c.FormValue("university")
    err := db.QueryRow("SELECT domain FROM universities WHERE name = $1", universitySelected).Scan(&domain)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return c.Render("signup", fiber.Map{
        "UniversityName": universitySelected,
        "UniversityDomain": domain,
    })
```

Comment: better to put log in HandleUniversitySelection and check Is this also get called when invoking HandleRegistration

Comment: Tried to put log in HandleUniversitySelection and it wasn't called after first time. I used other way to get the data I wanted.